# Merging a commit off of one branch, to be based off of another branch

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging, staging

I have a `master` branch and a `staging` branch for my project. I just pushed up a separate `develop` branch that is off of `master`, but I need it to be off of `staging`.

Is there anyway to take the `develop` branch which is 1 commit ahead of master and have it so it is off of my staging `branch`? So ultimately it would only be one commit ahead of `staging`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be tempted to suggest doing a simple rebase of `develop` on `staging`:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase staging
```

This would replay all the commits in `develop` which occurred *after* the point where `staging` diverged from `master` directly on top of the `staging` branch.  But this might also play certain `master` commits on top of `staging`, which does not sound like what you want.

So if all you want to do is to play that single commit on top of `staging` and have it be the `develop` branch, you can try this:

```
git checkout staging
git checkout -b new_develop
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 of single commit>
```

Then delete the old `develop` branch, and rename `new_develop` to `develop`:

```
git branch -d develop
git branch -m new_develop develop
```

Comment: Thanks dude, needed the second approach in this case.